# Is there an easy way of combining two JSON files or splitting one JSON in Ruby?

Tags: ruby

The first part of my question is that if I have two JSONs files (file_a.json, file_b.json) with records that are sorted by date.  How can I easily combine the two?

file_a.json:

```
[

    {
        "Date": "2012-11-19",
        "Open": 8.27,
        "High": 8.35,
        "Low": 8.21,
        "Close": 8.34,
        "Volume": 14606500,
        "Adj Close": 8.34
    },
    {
        "Date": "2012-11-15",
        "Open": 8.11,
        "High": 8.19,
        "Low": 8.02,
        "Close": 8.05,
        "Volume": 14798900,
        "Adj Close": 8.05
    }
]
```

file_b.json:

```
[
    {
        "Date": "2012-11-14",
        "Open": 8.33,
        "High": 8.36,
        "Low": 8.1,
        "Close": 8.13,
        "Volume": 14175500,
        "Adj Close": 8.13
    },
    {
        "Date": "2012-11-13",
        "Open": 8.36,
        "High": 8.44,
        "Low": 8.3,
        "Close": 8.31,
        "Volume": 11103900,
        "Adj Close": 8.31
    }
]
```

I thought about reading the first JSON, collecting all the fields, and then trying to write them to the second JSON (something like what I started below), but is there a better/easier way to simply join two JSONs sorted by date assuming that the second started where the first one left off?

```
json = File.read("file_a.json")
quotes = JSON.parse(json)
$close = quotes.collect {|quote| quote['Adj Close']}
```

Secondly, if I did have one JSON (same keys as above) - master.json and wanted to split it at some specified date, is there an easy way to do this?

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you could read both files and merge them:

```
master = %w[a b].map { |f| JSON.parse File.read("file_#{f}.json") }.flatten
```

`master` will now contain data from both files.

To split it down by some date:

```
require 'date'

start_date = Date.parse("2012-11-15") - 365
master_updated = master.select {|h| Date.parse(h["Date"]) >= start_date }
```

`master_updated` will contain only items with date >= 2011-11-15

To have it converted back to json use `master.to_json`

### [Here](http://cibox.org/slivu/stackoverflow?path=is-there-an-easy-way-of-combining-two-json-files-or-splitting-one-json-in-ruby&lang=ruby&file=app.rb&run=true#) is a live demo

(link no longer works)

Comment: Thanks @Slivu - I'm a little confused with the merge statement.  How is it recognizing the two filenames?  Is it merging any two files that have the prefix file_? My actual files are AA_UPDATED.json and AA_up_to_now_UPDATED.json (most recent records are in this file, [0] is most recent).  Would I then just replace `[a b]` with `[up_to_now_UPDATED UPDATED]` and change `"file_ ...` to `"AA_ ...`?  Thanks again

Comment: yes, just replace `%w[a b]` to your needs as well as `File.read("file_#{f}.json")`

Comment: Thanks again @Slivu (its running now, I'll mark it as correct when it completes) - could I ask a quick followup?  Using the Time class, for the `start_date = Time.parse("2012-11-15")` is there a way to make the start date, the current system date minus 365 days? Something like `start_date = Time.parse(Time.now - 365)`?

Comment: `Time.now - 365` will decrement 365 seconds rather than days. For days use `Date.today - 365`. For this to work make sure to `require 'date'` at the top of file

Comment: btw, for this to work you'll have to use `Date.parse` instead of `Time.parse`, or call `to_date` on time object, like `Time.parse(...).to_date`

Comment: which is better? Do i need to change anything on the second line of the split?  Does it stay Time.parse? or should I add .to_date after both instances of Time.parse()?

Comment: Thanks @Slivu - I'm getting this error: `NoMethodError: private method `select' called for #<String:0x6ad21538>`.  In the usage where its erroring, I'm specifying master by doing: master = File.read("file_a.json"), then doing a split - the split that occurs here is not the one we were just discussing (-365), this one has a fixed date.

Comment: pls do `master = JSON.parse(File.read("file_a.json"))` instead

Comment: Thanks again, now it's erroring with `NoMethodError: undefined method gsub!' for #<Date: 2012-11-21 (4912505/2,0,2299161)>` on the line: `start_date = Date.parse(Date.today) - 365`.  Could it be because I have no records from today?  The earliest record is for the 19th.

Comment: pls use `start_date = Date.today - 365` instead